# How to compute gradient of power function wrt exponent in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I am trying to compute the gradient of

```
out = x.sign()*torch.pow(x.abs(), alpha)
```

with respect to alpha.

I tried the following so far:

```
class Power(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, alpha=2.):
    super(Power, self).__init__()
    self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(alpha))

  def forward(self, x):
    return x.sign()*torch.abs(x)**self.alpha
```

but this class keeps giving me `nan` in training of my network. I expect to see something like `grad=out*torch.log(x)` but cannot get to it. This code, for instance, returns nothing:

```
alpha_rooting = Power()
x = torch.randn((1), device='cpu', dtype=torch.float)
out = (alpha_rooting(x)).sum()
out.backward()
print(out.grad)
```

I am trying to use `autograd` for this by no luck either. How should I go about solving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Power()` class that you have written works as expected. There is a problem in how you are using it actually. Gradients are stored in `.grad` of that variable and not the `out` variable as you have used above. You can change the code as below.

```
alpha_rooting = Power()
x = torch.randn((1), device='cpu', dtype=torch.float)
out = (alpha_rooting(x)).sum()

# compute gradients of all parameters with respect to out (dout/dparam)
out.backward()
# print gradient of alpha
# Note that gradients are store in .grad of parameter not out variable
print(alpha_rooting.alpha.grad)

# compare if it is approximately correct to exact grads
err = (alpha_rooting.alpha.grad - out*torch.log(x))**2 
if (err <1e-8):
    print("Gradients are correct")
```